# how to pass a value cell in csv file with jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

Can anyone help me with this case? I have a CSV file. Column A is Username, Column B is Password, Column C is a value (the value I want to insert to the database). In JMeter, can I login with A1, B1 to insert value1 then get the value from C2, C3 to insert value2, value3. Then continue login with A4, B4 to insert value4? I try a lot of ways to do that but it does not work.

I really need your help!!!!

CSV data

[image]

Comment: Did you try using with the different CSV file? For login, try to use one CSV file with credentials value and for inserting try with another CSV file with values.

Comment: yes i try. Using two different CSV file is OK but i just want only one CSV file!

Comment: Try to use the [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy). Check out the `File.readLines()` method which might be helpful for you.

Comment: can you explain or give me an example how to create groovy() function?

Comment: Check this article: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) setup:

[image: Example CSV Data Set Config]

You can design your test as follows:

- [IF Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller), condition: `"${user}" != ""`

  - "Login" Sampler
- "Insert Value" Sampler

So if `${user}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) is defined - JMeter will execute the "Login" sampler, and if it is not defined - it will proceed to the "Insert Value" sampler

Demo:

[image: CSV Data Set If Controller Empty Variable]

See [How to Use JMeter's 'IF' Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) article for more information on conditionally executing this or that requests in JMeter tests.